# How to separate files by the ninth digit

Tags: split, notepad++, notepad, notepad2

My idea would be to keep only the ones that contain the number "8" in the ninth position.

Example:
A list of numbers with 11 numbers each line

```
162156258 12 we keep this one because it's an "8" in the ninth position
612644264 75 this one would be deleted
621285076 89 this one would be deleted
872275028 72 this would be kept...

78686825079 
12801683230 
87545141857 
46821584818 
51704231523 
15256375253 
60512053812 
85746520080 
80014785137 
46648611847
```

Is it possible to do that in notepad? Is there any site I can do that? How could i do that? Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Notepad++

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\d{8}[^8].*\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
\d{8}       # 8 digits
[^8]        # a character that is not "8"
.*          # 0 or more any character
\R?         # any kind of linebreak, optional
```

**Screenshot (before):**
[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: omg, that was perfect, thank you so much

Comment: @IsraelCosta: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)